# Мотор arduino крутится только в одну сторону

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Ардуино должно делать поворот на 180 градусов и на -180 градусов с задержкой в 1 секунду, но работает только по часовой (180 градусов), против часовой (-180 градусов) не крутится
Используем библиотеку AmperkaStepper

Код:

```
// библиотека для работы с шаговым двигателем
#include <AmperkaStepper.h>
 
// создаём объект для работы с шаговым двигателем
// передаём фикированое количество шагов за полный оборот
// смотреть в характеристиках двигателя
AmperkaStepper motor(200);
 
// при использовании Motor Shield на нестандартных пинах
// необходимо педедавать управляющие пины
// Например, для пинов 8, 9, 10, 11
// AmperkaStepper motor(200, 8, 9, 10, 11);
 
void setup() {
  // устанавливаем скорость вращения 30 оборотов в минуту.
  motor.setSpeed(30);
}
 
void loop() {
  // 180° по часовой стрелке в двуфазном режиме
  motor.step(100, FULL_STEP);
  delay(1000);
 
  // 180° против часовой стрелки в однофазном режиме
  motor.step(-100, WAVE_DRIVE);
  delay(1000);
 
  // 180° по часовой стрелке в полушаговом режиме
  motor.step(200, HALF_STEP);
  delay(1000);
 
  // 180° против часовой стрелки в двуфазном режиме
  // этот режим используется по умолчанию, если не передан
  // второй аргумент
  motor.step(-100);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: проверь подключение пина напрправления

Comment: Какой тип двигателя, к каким пинам подключен? Если двигатель 28BYJ-48, то с огромной вероятностью у вас перепутаны пины.